# Poking a face with beveled sides?

Tags: edges, faces, bevel

I am fairly new to blender, and I am trying to make a terrain that has beveled sides, but I want the top to look low-poly. I tried flattening the top to make it a single face in hopes that the polygons near the edges of the face (shown below) would go away. However, when I went to poke the single face, all of the little polygons near the edges of the top face came back, and I can't poke those polygons like the middle gets poked. I want the **entire** face to poke out large polygons, just how the center of the face looks in the photo below.[image]

So my question is, is it possible to make it so that the **entire top face** gets poked like the middle of it? (get rid of all the small polygons near the edges of the face and turn it into one big face?). Also, after that, how can I make the edges that are *not* already beveled (the ones touching the top face) to be beveled, but not ruin the poked out faces? Thank you!

Comment: Hello :). Can you be more precise? It's not really clear what you want to achieve. What do you mean by *poke out large polygons*? :)

Comment: I mean that when I hit "poke faces" with the entire top face selected, I want the entire top face to look like the middle of it (in the picture), where the faces are large and not small like their surroundings. Right now, only the middle diamond is doing what I want it to do. Sorry if I can't explain this well.